# Tool or terminal with command output occurance indicator?

Tags: command-line, terminal-emulator

Firefox's [Web console messages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Console_messages) have (like many other browsers) an occurrence indicator. Did a similar feat ever get adopted or considered for terminal output on any platform? Would it be feasible to have this type of command output interpretation not affect performance too much?

I'm not sure about the exact nature for general-purpose output parsing, but the motivation for it is to have similar lines retain their position on the screen to minimize redrawing and for humans to be visually cognizant of live process output (most likely compiler jobs) in stead of them scrolling through a log file after the fact.

related: [showing-differences-in-output](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/32067/improved-watch-run-command-repeatedly-showing-differences-in-output)